# How to disable all breakpoint on selenium Webdriver with Java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want disable all breakpoint (come from `debugger;` javascript target app) on selenium Webdriver with Java. My target app run a breakpoint every x seconds **and stop my selenium run**.

[image]

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");

options.addArguments("--disable-  ???? ");     <= ???????

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("http://rd.huangpuqu.sh.cn/website/html/shprd/shprd_tpxw/List/list_0.htm");
```

you can find all chome option [here](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) but I do not find this feature.

**EDIT:**

I try this (by Javascript via JavascriptExecutor) but do not work:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("debugger; = function(){};");
```

or

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("debugger = function(){};");
```

or

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.debugger = function(){};");
```

**EDIT 2:**

I try fix this issue by javascript but do not work:

stackoverflow: [How to disable debugger; command in JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56752085/how-to-disable-debugger-command-in-js)

**debugger is not a JavaScript member, it can't be overridden.**

**EDIT 3:**

in the meantime, I asked a new issue on the selenium library [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/7328)

Comment: How do your application create a breakpoint every x seconds?

Comment: @g.annunziata, the target application is not mine. He surely did this to block selenium robots.

Answer (score 0):

Seems good idea to call script to redefine **debugger**, but I think you can try this:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("debugger = function(){};");
```

or:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.debugger = function(){};");
```

Comment: I had already tried with that but `"debugger = function(){};"` is syntax error and `"window.debugger = function(){};"` it does not work

Comment: I create new issue on chromium https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=978794&can=2&q=debugger%3B