# How to disable debugger; command in JS?

Tags: javascript, debugging

```
window.alert = function(msg){console.log('foo' + msg);};
alert("bar");
```

> foobar

screenshot of chrome console:

[image]

My problem is if I try disable `debugger;` command with this, do not work:

```
window.debugger = function(){console.log('faa');};
debugger;
```

when I run `debugger;`, breakpoint stop my app.

Comment: Why do you want to disable `debugger`? It's a *keyword*, not a function - you can't change how it works. You shouldn't really be using this unless debugging. At best, you might have a build step that strips any `debugger` statements but, again, that shouldn't be a requirement.

Comment: @VLAZ, I want disable `debugger;` by selenium because my target app use this (is not my app), I am a tester of Web app.

Comment: The question is very fundamentally the wrong one here: really, the app *shouldn't* be using `debugger`. If it does, I'd advise you to return it and say that it doesn't pass testing. If you need to be hacking the website just to get the test to work, what about the average user?

Comment: `debugger;` is not seen by average users because the debugger (F12) is not open. You can find here the target app: http://rd.huangpuqu.sh.cn/website/html/shprd/shprd_tpxw/List/list_0.htm

Comment: Unless the browser executes the breakpoints even if the dev tools are not open. It's still wrong to leave dev artefacts in a non-dev build. It's equivalent to shipping a commercial product with debug symbols enabled and with the `DEBUG = TRUE` added and stuff.

Comment: @VLAZ, if they did that it was deliberately to block the selelium robots.

Comment: If it's for protection, but you can easily remove it, then what good is it as protection?

Comment: @VLAZ, precisely, this protection is not easy to remove, that's why I search on stackoverflow

Comment: But if it was possible to remove, then the protection doesn't work. So it successfully blocks tests. It's not possible to both be "protected" and to also have tests for the page - the two are incompatible. If you can test it, then anybody can bypass the "protection". If you can't bypass the protection, then you cannot test the application. The whole "protection" aspect doesn't work, really, when you consider that a bot might just use something different to Selenium to scrape pages and wouldn't be hindered.

Comment: @VLAZ, if a human can do something Selenium can do it in the same way, that's the purpose of my research. I work on NoraUi (Gherkin / Cucumber / Selenium). I created a new issue on selenium to add a new option in the following list: https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Answer (score 0):

`debugger` is not a member of `window`, it's only a sign for the browser to know to stop there on debug mode.

Comment: `debugger = function(){console.log('faa');};` is the same result (do not work)

Comment: debugger is not a JavaScript member, it can't be overridden.